# Rendering a partial multiple times in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to render a view in a template multiple times with different data each time, specifically like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="foobar">
    {{render "_people" peopleArray}}
    <!-- ... -->
    {{render "_people" anotherPeopleArray}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_people">
    {{#each person in controller}}
       {{person.name}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

I get the JS error: "assertion failed: This view is already rendered".

If I change the `{{render "_people"}}` to `{{partial "people"}}` then it will render multiple times, but I do not know how to pass different data into there.

To clarify, I to be able to create a partial/view, which I can pass data to, and can call multiple times. I'm sure this is simple and I'm just missing something.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `{{render}}` only once. If you need to do it multiple times, use `{{control}}` instead, such as:

`{{control "people" peopleArray}}`

This will create a `people` template with `PeopleView` and `PeopleController` with it's `content` set to `peopleArray`

Comment: To use this with rails-ember, you currently need to add controlID: 
{{control widget content controlID="one"}}
{{control widget content controlID="two"}}

(http://bit.ly/XPOu5i)

Comment: Is this a new feature? Can you point to documentation / examples explaining this?

Comment: @Sherwin This is very new and currently only available on master https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/control.js ... the only documentation is https://gist.github.com/9ceed5d6708c655d3402

Comment: NOTE: At the current time you need to enable experimental helpers to use the control helper. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/control.js#L10